# Generating syntatic label data vector

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I have a binary classification problem with a generic Y vector of variable size like this:

```
y = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 .. ]
```

I want to generate a syntactic Y vector (same size) with different accuracy like

```
y_1 = [ ... ] 50% accuracy
y_2 = [ ... ] 60% accuracy
y_3 = [ ... ] 70% accuracy
y_4 = [ ... ] whatever % accuracy
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?
Instead of manually editing the vector every time?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: So you have multiple classifiers, each classifier produces a prediction (y_1, y_2 and so on) ? And you want to run those predictions against your truth y?

Comment: No, I have the correct label vector Y with 100% accuracy. 
For testing some stuffs, I want to generate a vector with specific accuracy using the vector Y as a reference.
For example I want y_1 with 70% accuracy, using Y as reference to generate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
from sklearn import metrics
def generateAccVectors(y_truth, percentage):
  y = list(y_truth)
  for i in range(len(y)):
    if metrics.accuracy_score(y_truth, y)<= percentage:
      break
    if(y[i] ==1):
      y[i]= 0
    else:
      y[i] =1
  return y
```

Of course this won't generate vectors with the exact accuracy if the numer of labels is not divisible through the percentage.

Example:

```
from sklearn import metrics
y = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 ] 
y_1= generateAccVectors(y, 0.85)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y, y_1))
#output: 0.8333333333333334
```